# JASidePanel Swipe doesn't work after push new controller on navigation stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I use [JaSidePanel](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels) to achieve effect like in Facebook App. But I have some problem with it.

[image: storyboard]

(1) is subclass of JASidePanelController, Navigation Controller is added as center panel. Everything works fine, but after I push new View Controller to Navigation Controller I'm not able to make swip gesture to show Table View (4 - Left Panel). Is there some way around or I'm doing something wrong.

**[EDIT]**
Ok I found why this did occur, JaSidePanel has property panningLimitedToTopViewController that has to be set to NO in order to allow swipe gesture on diffrent view controller that one on top.

Comment: you can answer your own question and check it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

jaSidePanelController.panningLimitedToTopViewController = NO;